# Call Lua script in xcode, an error occured

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, lua

I have added all lua source files in xcode, then build successfully, but have error when run.
after load the lua file, it comes out the error when use pcall method.
Here is the code:

```
p_lua_stack_ = luaL_newstate();
luaL_openlibs(p_lua_stack_);
FilePathManager *m = [FilePathManager sharedInstance];
int r = luaL_loadfile(p_lua_stack_, [[m llkFacadeFilePath] UTF8String]);
DLog(@"%@", [m llkFacadeFilePath]);
DPRINT("%d", r);
//DPRINT("%d", lua_pcall(p_lua_stack_, 0, 0, 0));
int cr = lua_pcall(p_lua_stack_, 0, 0, 0);
LuaStateUtil *util = LuaStateUtil::GetSharedInstancePointer();
util->PrintPcallReturnValue(cr);  //print return value info
DPRINT("%s", lua_tostring(p_lua_stack_, -1)); //when run to this line, the output is...
```

The output is:...4-489C-4A40-8582-F734FAAC428D/LLK.app/llk_facade.lua:1: attempt to call global 'module' (a nil value)

Then I am totally confused because "module" is a library method of Lua.
Who can help me, please?

maybe this question read a little hard, i'm not good at English.

Answer (score 0):

If that is Lua 5.2, you need to enable `module` by defining `LUA_COMPAT_MODULE`.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but LUA_COMPAT_MODULE is defined, not this reason